# NKAssetDownload return nil instance

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to create a newsstand application, but while trying to download the selected pdf the asset download returns nil. 
What is the problem?

```
 -(void)downloadIssueAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
    {
      NKLibrary *nkLib = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];
      NKIssue *nkIssue = [nkLib issueWithName:[publisher nameOfIssueAtIndex:index]];                 

     if (nkIssue == nil)
     {
    nkIssue = [nkLib addIssueWithName:[publisher nameOfIssueAtIndex:index] date:[NSDate date]];  

    }
if ([nkIssue status] != NKIssueContentStatusNone)
    return;
NSLog(@"%@",nkIssue);
NSURL *downloadURL = [publisher contentURLForIssueWithName:nkIssue.name];
NSLog(@"%@",downloadURL);
if(!downloadURL) return;
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL];
NSLog(@"%@",req);
//req shows the correct url request

NKAssetDownload *assetDownload = [nkIssue addAssetWithRequest:req];
//assetDownload is nil

NSLog(@"%@",assetDownload);
 [assetDownload setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:index],@"Index",
                            nil]];
[assetDownload downloadWithDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I this it return nil because `[NKLibrary sharedLibrary];` does too.

Maybe you should try to add your app to Newsstand by adding the `UINewsstandApp` to your Info.plist and then set it to `YES`.